# Side by Side Div's with Close Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone help me?

Looking at making a side by side stream and chat, but being able to close the chat and widening the stream like Twitch.tv.

So about chat div box you will have Open/Close Chat.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What you are asking is incredibly broad. StackOverflow is for asking questions about specific problems you are having with code you have written.

Comment: I am asking a specific problem... I've seen people asking questions like this before with helpful answers.

Comment: Provide some code of what you have tried so far. Also a demo on jsfiddle, even if it's broken, is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/d77nqru9/

I a using a simple jQuery script to achieve the same effect like on twitch

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.chat-toggle').click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('chat-close')) {
            $('#content').css('width', '100%');
            $('#chat').css('width', '0px');
            $(this).removeClass('chat-close').addClass('chat-open');
        } else {
            $('#content').css('width', '80%');
            $('#chat').css('width', '20%');
            $(this).removeClass('chat-open').addClass('chat-close');
        }
    });
});
```

On clicking the toggle div it will change the sizes of the content and chat div's. The current state of the chat (open or close) is determined by the class of the toggle div.